# How to implement ItemChange for many Outlook subfolders?

Tags: vba, outlook

In a VBA module in Outlook I have currently code like this:

```
Private WithEvents AAInboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents AASentItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents AADoneItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub AAInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    'Do Something
End Sub
Private Sub AASentItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    'Do Something
End Sub
Private Sub AADoneItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

Above is not the complete code, just to show the principle. This works fine for a couple of folders for which I implemented this.

I would like to have such events for all subfolders of the Inbox. And this should work dynamically. If the user creates a new sub-folder then I don't want to change the code. **I want to have an event which fires when an item is changed in any Outlook Inbox subfolder.**

**Is that possible? How?**

**Edit:** With Dmitry Streblechenko's answer I tried the following but it does not do what I want it to do - maybe I implemented it incorrectly.
The events fire but only for the last assigned folder and not all folders.
This is what I expected but maybe I made something wrong or didn't understand the answer correct. I put this information in the question because it won't fit in a comment to Dmitry's answer.

The following are the most important parts of the code. I leave lots of details out to make it shorter. Basically it works, but only for one folder.

```
Option Explicit
Global gbl_FolderItems(3) As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents FolderItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    For intI = 1 To 3
        'This works only with the last folder
        'Set gbl_FolderItems(intI) = objGetFolderItems("Folder" & intI)
        'Set FolderItems = gbl_FolderItems(intI)

        'This works only with the last folder
        Set FolderItems = objGetFolderItems("Folder" & intI)
        Set gbl_FolderItems(intI) = FolderItems
    Next
End Sub

Private Function objGetFolderItems(strFolderShortName As String) As Outlook.Items
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim obj As Outlook.Items

    Select Case strFolderShortName
    Case "Folder1"
        Set obj = objNS.Folders("MyAccount").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Folder1").Items
    Case "Folder2"
        Set obj = objNS.Folders("MyAccount").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Folder2").Items
    Case "Folder3"
        Set obj = objNS.Folders("MyAccount").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Folder1").Folders("Folder3").Items
    End Select
    Set objGetFolderItems = obj
End Function

Private Sub FolderItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Debug.Print "FolderItems_ItemChange(" & Item.Subject & ")"
End Sub

Private Sub FolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Debug.Print "FolderItems_ItemAdd(" & Item.Subject & ")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider creating a COM add-in instead. In that case you will be able to subscribe to folder events dynamically. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) for more information.

Also you may consider using a low-level API - Extended MAPI. See [MAPI Notification Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc840027.aspx) for more information. Or just use any third-party wrappers around that API such as Redemption.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a look at that and I created my first Add-In with VS and C# - it's not too difficult. I will look if I can get Dmitry Streblechenko's answer to work and then I will decide which way I will go.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a single WithEvents Items variable, loop through the folders that you want to track, assign the Items variable, and store it in a global array. Even though the variable will be overwritten on each iteration, all of the folders will be monitored because all the different Items objects are still alive and raising events since they are referenced by the array.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to implements this but I can't make it work. I added the code to my question. It would be great if you can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, it's pure VBA, however it's not so straightforward:

1. create a **HandlerClass** with singular event *NewItem* and one public method to *raise* it from outside of the class:

```
Public Event NewItem(ByVal Item As Object)

Public Sub raise(ByVal Item As Object)
  RaiseEvent NewItem(Item)
End Sub
```

2. create a **FolderWatcherClass** holding singular folder and handling its Items' *ItemAdd* event:

```
Private folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Private WithEvents fItems As Outlook.Items
Private handler As CLAhandler

Public Sub init(f As Outlook.MAPIFolder, h As CLAhandler)
  Set folder = f
  Set fItems = f.Items
  Set handler = h
End Sub

Private Sub fItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Call handler.raise(Item)
End Sub
```

3. You have the two classes defined now, so declare the handler and array of watchers in the module:

```
Private WithEvents commonEventHandler As HandlerClass
Private folderWatchers() As FolderWatcherClass
```

then initialize them

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  ' create new WithEvents handler object, common to all folderWatchers
  Set commonEventHandler = New HandlerClass
  ' hook folder handlers
  ' start with the Inbox, then traverse recursively all the subfolders
  Call ProcessFolder(Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox))
End Sub


Private Sub ProcessFolder(ByVal thisFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
  Dim subFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim u As Long
  
  ' tricky check if the folderWatchers array has been initialized - assuming its UBound 'sbeen not initialized to -1 :)
  u = -1
  On Error Resume Next
  u = UBound(folderWatchers)
  On Error GoTo 0
  
  ' redim the array
  If u = -1 Then
    ' the first folder, presumably the Inbox itself
    ReDim folderWatchers(1 To 1)
  Else
    ' all the subsequent subfolders
    ReDim Preserve folderWatchers(1 To UBound(folderList) + 1)
  End If
  
  ' store a new instance of folder watcher in the array
  Set folderWatchers(UBound(folderWatchers)) = New FolderWatcherClass
  ' initialize it (WithEvents in the FolderWatcherClass!) with the thisFolder and the common event handler
  Call folderWatchers(UBound(folderWatchers)).init(thisFolder, commonEventHandler) ' pass THE SAME common event handler to each of the watchers!
  
  ' process the subfolders in the current folder recursively
  If (thisFolder.Folders.Count > 0) Then
    For Each subFolder In thisFolder.Folders
        If subFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then Call ProcessFolder(subFolder) ' process only the folders containing mail items
    Next
  End If
  ' you can refine the criteria above to watch only specified folders if needed
End Sub
```

Now it's the only one thing left to make it work, we have to handle the common event:

```
Private Sub commonEventHandler_NewItem(ByVal Item As Object)
  ' do whatever you like here
End Sub
```

*Summarizing:*

1. The **HandlerClass** provides singular event handler for all the folders
2. The **FolderWatcherClass** array holds each of the folders redirecting their *ItemAdd* events to the common **HandlerClass** object

*Disclaimer:* I renamed variables, methods and objects used in my original code to make them more understandable - I hope I've done it consequently and the code is consistent :)

Comment: Ah, the event in question was _ItemChange_ - I presented _ItemAdd_ here for this was what I needed, but the method described above can be used for any of the folder events as well.