# How can I apply an ItemChange event to each folder in a collection?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following (pseudo)code to create an event handler for a specific folder:

```
Private myFolder As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents myItems As Outlook.Items

Set myItems = myFolder.Items

Private Sub myItems.ItemChange( ... )
```

This is great for detecting changes in "myFolder" alone. But suppose I have another folder "myFolders" which itself contains many folders, and I would like to detect item changes in any of those folders, ie. in each member of `myFolders.Folders`. Is this possible?

Comment: So you wanna monitor subfolders for items changed and if there are new folders monitor them too? Would use the [FolderChange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.folderchange) to add the monitored folders to the collection. Your code would go in a class that can take the folder to monitor as a parameter. I don't know if I understand you well.

Comment: On a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034435/how-to-implement-itemchange-for-many-outlook-subfolders), there is an [idea proposed to use a global array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047927/1571407) of folder items for a single event. Whether the idea is faulty or my attempted implementation is faulty I could only trigger the event on the last folder added.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one `WithEvents`.  For example:

```
Private WithEvents InboxOneItems As Items
Private WithEvents InboxTwoItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set InboxOneItems = Session.Folders("JohnDoe@Isp1.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
  Set InboxTwoItems = Session.Folders("DoeJohn@Isp2.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
End Sub

Private Sub InboxOneItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Call ItemAdd("One", Item)
End Sub

Private Sub InboxTwoItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  Call ItemAdd("Two", Item)
End Sub

Sub ItemAdd(ByVal IdInbox As String, ByVal Item As Object)
  ' Code to process new emails from either mailbox
End If
```

I have two email addresses.  The Outlook wizard created a separate store and Inbox for each address.  The above code allows me to monitor both mailboxes and pass mail items arriving in either mailbox to a single routine for processing.

I have only used this approach to monitor two folders but I assume it will work with more.  This approach should work for a limited number of children of `myFolder` for which you would need pre-written code.

Were you hoping for something more dynamic?  Do want to be able to add a new child or grandchild folder to `MyFolder` and have Outlook immediately start monitoring it.  If such functionality exists, I hope someone explains how to use it because I would find it helpful.

Comment: On a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034435/how-to-implement-itemchange-for-many-outlook-subfolders), there is an [idea proposed to use a global array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047927/1571407) of folder items for a single event. Whether the idea is faulty or my attempted implementation is faulty I could only trigger the event on the last folder added.

Comment: @niton  Perhaps a message to Dmitry Streblechenko asking for a fuller explanation would help.